# Connect MYSQL using php and creating Database if not exist

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to learn php with best methods and practice but im not able to get proper output as per the code as there is no error!
is it a good method to create the database if not exist because im not getting output `echo "Database $dbname created successfully\n";`

```
<?php  
$user = "root";
$pwd = "";
$server = "localhost";
$dbname = "xyz";

//Connecting to MYSQL
$db_conn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pwd);
if (!$db_conn) {
    die("Connection Error".mysqli_error());
}
echo "Connected Successfully";

$db_select = mysqli_select_db($db_conn,$dbname);
if (!$db_select) {
  // If we couldn't, then it either doesn't exist, or we can't see it.
  //Create Database Query
    $db_create = "CREATE DATABASE $dbname";
    $db_selected = mysqli_query($db_conn,$db_create);

  if ($db_selected) {
      echo "Database $dbname created successfully\n";
      mysqli_select_db($db_conn,$dbname);
  } else {
      echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: do you get this line `echo "Connected Successfully";`??

Comment: yes i have received that output ! but fail to get the database output

Comment: change the database creation line to `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname`

Comment: sure, but may i know if im connected to database i should receive an error msg that error creating database - if im not wrong

Comment: check if the database is there by phpmyadmin

Comment: @Akintunde the database is been created in mysql, but im confused about echo statement - why it is not getting printed out

Comment: @AyushAgarwal  you are mixing `mysql_*` with `mysqli_*` , which is bad. check here:- `echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";`

Comment: @AlivetoDie can you share me link so that i can check out the different syntax of `mysql_` and `mysqli_`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

i got a solution out of it !
please check weather its a good method and best practice to add database !

```
$db_conn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pwd);
if (!$db_conn) {
    die("Connection Error".mysqli_error());
}
echo "Connected Successfully";
$db_select = mysqli_select_db($db_conn,$dbname);
if (!$db_select) {
  // If we couldn't, then it either doesn't exist, or we can't see it.
  //Create Database Query
    $db_create = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $dbname";
    $db_selected = mysqli_query($db_conn,$db_create);

  if ($db_selected) {
      echo "Database $dbname created successfully\n";
  } else {
      echo 'Error creating database: ' . mysqli_error() . "\n";
  }
}
 else{
    echo "Database $dbname is connected";
}
```